# Are IDEX printers able to make gradients?

Tags: filament, desktop-printer, dual-nozzle

I know that a single mixing nozzle with dual filament input can blend them in order to make gradients. I also know that IDEX means you have two independent nozzles and you can make objects with different materials (or colors).

But I don't understand if an IDEX printer can still "mix" (on the layer of course) the two filaments to create a gradient. My common sense says it's not possible, but I didn't find a proof of that.

I'm NOT interested in a mixing nozzle as most of the time I will need two different kind of filaments. The gradient with IDEX is just a "nice-to-have" feature. Not mandatory, but I would know before choose my next printer.

Comment: There's much better ways to get gradients or indeed full colour pictures that only require one nozzle

Comment: @Kilisi it would be useful to add a link to some resources then

Comment: Just commented because it only touches the question tangentially, and I don't know if the resources exist as far as I know it might be just my lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the task from the creation reference. An IDEX printer requires the slicer to direct each nozzle to a specific location of the model while it is being created. No true gradient could be accomplished as it would require both nozzles to be in nearly-instant-extrusion proximity.

I suppose one could create a matrix of colors in a manner similar to that of RGB LED color displays, but that's a severe stretch of the imagination. It would require perhaps a strong understanding of [full g-code control](http://fullcontrolgcode.com/) to place the individual lines. Additionally, there would be a limitation to two colors and the combinations thereof, although with the bi-color Quantum style filament, results might be interesting.